# SSO using SAML 2.0 on ADFS server

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, adfs

One of my client has an ADFS system and we are trying to implement SSO using SAML 2.0 and spring boot.

When they load the web site, it comes up with an error. I can see in the log :

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Incoming SAML message is invalid
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:96) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Unsupported request
    at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.getBinding(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:265) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:172) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

My Spring boot project is based on this project i found on github https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample

I have changed the following class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {

    @Value("${saml.idp.metadata.file}")
    String metadataFilePath;

    @Value("${server.ssl.key-store}")
    String keystore;
    @Value("${server.ssl.key-store-password}")
    String storepass;
    @Value("${server.ssl.key-alias}")
    String keyAlias;
    @Value("${server.ssl.key-password}")
    String keyPass;

    // private Timer backgroundTaskTimer;
    private MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager;

    public void init() {
        // backgroundTaskTimer = new Timer(true);
        multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        // backgroundTaskTimer.purge();
        // backgroundTaskTimer.cancel();
        multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.shutdown();
    }

    @Autowired
    private SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl samlUserDetailsServiceImpl;

    // Initialization of the velocity engine
    @Bean
    public VelocityEngine velocityEngine() {
        return VelocityFactory.getEngine();
    }

    // XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing
    @Bean(initMethod = "initialize")
    public StaticBasicParserPool parserPool() {
        return new StaticBasicParserPool();
    }

    @Bean(name = "parserPoolHolder")
    public ParserPoolHolder parserPoolHolder() {
        return new ParserPoolHolder();
    }

    // Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages
    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() {
        return new HttpClient(multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager);
    }

    // SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML
    // messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider() {
        SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider = new SAMLAuthenticationProvider();
        samlAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetails(samlUserDetailsServiceImpl);
        samlAuthenticationProvider.setForcePrincipalAsString(false);
        return samlAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    // Provider of default SAML Context
    @Bean
    public SAMLContextProviderImpl contextProvider() {
        return new SAMLContextProviderImpl();
    }

    // Initialization of OpenSAML library
    @Bean
    public static SAMLBootstrap sAMLBootstrap() {
        return new CustomSAMLBootstrap();
    }

    // Logger for SAML messages and events
    @Bean
    public SAMLDefaultLogger samlLogger() {
        return new SAMLDefaultLogger();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumer webSSOprofileConsumer() {
        return new WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOprofileConsumer() {
        return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfile webSSOprofile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOProfile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 ECP profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileECPImpl ecpprofile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileECPImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public SingleLogoutProfile logoutprofile() {
        return new SingleLogoutProfileImpl();
    }

    // Central storage of cryptographic keys
    @Bean
    public KeyManager keyManager() {
        ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource(keystore);

        String storePass = storepass;
        Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<>();
        passwords.put(keyAlias, keyPass);
        return new JKSKeyManager(classPathResource, storePass, passwords, keyAlias);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileOptions defaultWebSSOProfileOptions() {
        WebSSOProfileOptions webSSOProfileOptions = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
        webSSOProfileOptions.setIncludeScoping(false);
        return webSSOProfileOptions;
    }

    // Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from
    // properties file
    @Bean
    public SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint() {
        SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint = new SAMLEntryPoint();
        samlEntryPoint.setDefaultProfileOptions(defaultWebSSOProfileOptions());
        return samlEntryPoint;
    }

    // Setup advanced info about metadata
    @Bean
    public ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata() {
        ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
        extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryEnabled(true);
        extendedMetadata.setSigningAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
        extendedMetadata.setSignMetadata(true);
        extendedMetadata.setEcpEnabled(true);
        return extendedMetadata;
    }

    // IDP Discovery Service
    @Bean
    public SAMLDiscovery samlIDPDiscovery() {
        SAMLDiscovery idpDiscovery = new SAMLDiscovery();
        idpDiscovery.setIdpSelectionPath("/saml/discovery");
        return idpDiscovery;
    }

    //  @Bean
    //  @Qualifier("idp-ssocircle")
    //  public ExtendedMetadataDelegate ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider()
    //          throws MetadataProviderException {
    //      String idpSSOCircleMetadataURL = "https://idp.ssocircle.com/meta-idp.xml";
    //      HTTPMetadataProvider httpMetadataProvider = new HTTPMetadataProvider(
    //              this.backgroundTaskTimer, httpClient(), idpSSOCircleMetadataURL);
    //      httpMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
    //      ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate =
    //              new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(httpMetadataProvider, extendedMetadata());
    //      extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(true);
    //      extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
    //      backgroundTaskTimer.purge();
    //      return extendedMetadataDelegate;
    //  }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("idp-ssocircle")
    public ExtendedMetadataDelegate ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider()
            throws MetadataProviderException {

        ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource(metadataFilePath);

        File samlMetadata = null;
        try {
            samlMetadata = classPathResource.getFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FilesystemMetadataProvider filesystemMetadataProvider = null;
        try {
            filesystemMetadataProvider = new FilesystemMetadataProvider(samlMetadata);
        } catch (MetadataProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        filesystemMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());

        ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate = new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(filesystemMetadataProvider, extendedMetadata());

        extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(true);
        extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
        return extendedMetadataDelegate;

    }

    // IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust
    // is here
    // Do no forget to call iniitalize method on providers
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("metadata")
    public CachingMetadataManager metadata() throws MetadataProviderException {
        List<MetadataProvider> providers = new ArrayList<MetadataProvider>();
        providers.add(ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider());
        return new CachingMetadataManager(providers);
    }

    // Filter automatically generates default SP metadata
    @Bean
    public MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator() {
        MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
        metadataGenerator.setEntityId("test");
        metadataGenerator.setExtendedMetadata(extendedMetadata());
        metadataGenerator.setIncludeDiscoveryExtension(false);
        metadataGenerator.setKeyManager(keyManager());
        return metadataGenerator;
    }

    // The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix
    // and presents SP metadata there
    @Bean
    public MetadataDisplayFilter metadataDisplayFilter() {
        return new MetadataDisplayFilter();
    }

    // Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login
    @Bean
    public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler =
                new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/landing");
        return successRedirectHandler;
    }

    // Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login
    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler =
                new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        failureHandler.setUseForward(true);
        failureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/error");
        return failureHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter = new SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter();
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        return samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter;
    }

    // Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter = new SAMLProcessingFilter();
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        return samlWebSSOProcessingFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MetadataGeneratorFilter metadataGeneratorFilter() {
        return new MetadataGeneratorFilter(metadataGenerator());
    }

    // Handler for successful logout
    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler() {
        SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler = new SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler();
        successLogoutHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
        return successLogoutHandler;
    }

    // Logout handler terminating local session
    @Bean
    public SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler() {
        SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler =
                new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
        logoutHandler.setInvalidateHttpSession(true);
        logoutHandler.setClearAuthentication(true);
        return logoutHandler;
    }

    // Filter processing incoming logout messages
    // First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful
    // global logout
    @Bean
    public SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter samlLogoutProcessingFilter() {
        return new SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter(successLogoutHandler(),
                logoutHandler());
    }

    // Overrides default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML
    // messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLLogoutFilter samlLogoutFilter() {
        return new SAMLLogoutFilter(successLogoutHandler(),
                new LogoutHandler[] { logoutHandler() },
                new LogoutHandler[] { logoutHandler() });
    }

    // Bindings
    private ArtifactResolutionProfile artifactResolutionProfile() {
        final ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl artifactResolutionProfile =
                new ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl(httpClient());
        artifactResolutionProfile.setProcessor(new SAMLProcessorImpl(soapBinding()));
        return artifactResolutionProfile;
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPArtifactBinding artifactBinding(ParserPool parserPool, VelocityEngine velocityEngine) {
        return new HTTPArtifactBinding(parserPool, velocityEngine, artifactResolutionProfile());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPSOAP11Binding soapBinding() {
        return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPPostBinding httpPostBinding() {
        return new HTTPPostBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding httpRedirectDeflateBinding() {
        return new HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPSOAP11Binding httpSOAP11Binding() {
        return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPPAOS11Binding httpPAOS11Binding() {
        return new HTTPPAOS11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    // Processor
    @Bean
    public SAMLProcessorImpl processor() {
        Collection<SAMLBinding> bindings = new ArrayList<SAMLBinding>();
        bindings.add(httpRedirectDeflateBinding());
        bindings.add(httpPostBinding());
        bindings.add(artifactBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine()));
        bindings.add(httpSOAP11Binding());
        bindings.add(httpPAOS11Binding());
        return new SAMLProcessorImpl(bindings);
    }

    /**
     * Define the security filter chain in order to support SSO Auth by using SAML 2.0
     *
     * @return Filter chain proxy
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Bean
    public FilterChainProxy samlFilter() throws Exception {
        List<SecurityFilterChain> chains = new ArrayList<SecurityFilterChain>();
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/login/**"),
                samlEntryPoint()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/logout/**"),
                samlLogoutFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/metadata/**"),
                metadataDisplayFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSO/**"),
                samlWebSSOProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSOHoK/**"),
                samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SingleLogout/**"),
                samlLogoutProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/discovery/**"),
                samlIDPDiscovery()));
        return new FilterChainProxy(chains);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the authentication manager currently used by Spring.
     * It represents a bean definition with the aim allow wiring from
     * other classes performing the Inversion of Control (IoC).
     *
     * @throws  Exception
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    /**
     * Defines the web based security configuration.
     *
     * @param   http It allows configuring web based security for specific http requests.
     * @throws  Exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());
        http
        .addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(samlFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http
        .logout()
        .disable(); // The logout procedure is already handled by SAML filters.
    }

    /**
     * Sets a custom authentication provider.
     *
     * @param   auth SecurityBuilder used to create an AuthenticationManager.
     * @throws  Exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        shutdown();
    }

}
```

How can i get more information of the unsupported request ?

EDIT, i tried to output in the log the request message i received by using a custom SAMLProcessorImpl :

```
public class CustomSAMLProcessorImpl extends SAMLProcessorImpl {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomSAMLProcessorImpl.class);
    public CustomSAMLProcessorImpl(Collection<SAMLBinding> bindings) {
        super(bindings);
    }

    @Override
    public SAMLMessageContext retrieveMessage(SAMLMessageContext samlContext) throws SAMLException, MetadataProviderException, MessageDecodingException, SecurityException {
        log(samlContext);
        return super.retrieveMessage(samlContext);
    }

    public void log(SAMLMessageContext context) {

        // Log operation
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (context.getInboundMessageTransport() != null) {
            HTTPInTransport transport = (HTTPInTransport) context.getInboundMessageTransport();
            sb.append(transport.getPeerAddress());
        }

        // Log local entity ID
        sb.append(";");
        if (context.getLocalEntityId() != null) {
            sb.append(context.getLocalEntityId());
        }

        // Log peer entity ID
        sb.append(";");
        if (context.getPeerEntityId() != null) {
            sb.append(context.getPeerEntityId());
        }



        // Log SAML message
        sb.append(";");
        try {
            if (context.getInboundSAMLMessage() != null) {
                String messageStr = XMLHelper.nodeToString(SAMLUtil.marshallMessage(context.getInboundSAMLMessage()));
                sb.append(messageStr);
            }
            if (context.getOutboundSAMLMessage() != null) {
                String messageStr = XMLHelper.nodeToString(SAMLUtil.marshallMessage(context.getOutboundSAMLMessage()));
                sb.append(messageStr);
            }
        } catch (MessageEncodingException e1) {
            LOG.warn("Error marshaling message during logging", e1);
        }

        LOG.info("---------------- AUDIT TRAIL START---------------");
        LOG.info(sb.toString());
        LOG.info("---------------- AUDIT TRAIL END---------------");

    }

}
```

I have then editing the WebSecurityConfig to be as follow :

```
@Bean
public SAMLProcessorImpl processor() {
    Collection<SAMLBinding> bindings = new ArrayList<SAMLBinding>();
    bindings.add(httpRedirectDeflateBinding());
    bindings.add(httpPostBinding());
    bindings.add(artifactBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine()));
    bindings.add(httpSOAP11Binding());
    bindings.add(httpPAOS11Binding());
    return new CustomSAMLProcessorImpl(bindings);
}
```

In the log i see :

```
---------------- AUDIT TRAIL START---------------
 XXX.XX.XX.XX;test;;
 ---------------- AUDIT TRAIL END---------------
```

Comment: Not clear what exactly is your problem, is it with spring boot error or you have an issue in saml connection to ADFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to rebuild my project from scratch from the repository https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample and it works.